# Parsing problematic JSON with Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I am trying to parse JSON objects, which are generally of the form

```
{
  "objects": [a bunch of records that can assume a few different forms],
  "parameters": [same deal],
  "values": {
              "k1": "v1",
              "k2": "v2",
              ...
            }
}
```

using Haskell's Aeson library.  Part of this task is simple in the sense that the `parameters` and `values` fields need no custom parsing whatsoever (and so seem to need only a generically derived instance of `FromJSON`), and *most* of the records contained within the array associated to `objects` also need no special parsing.  However, there are some parts of parsing the records within the array of `objects` that, when considered separately, have documented solutions, but together present problems that I haven't figured out how to address.

Now, the possible variants of record inside the `objects` and `parameters` arrays are finite in number and often contain the same keys; for example, all of them have a "name" key or an "id" key, or such.  But also many of them have a "type" key, which is a reserved keyword, and so cannot be parsed generically.  This is the first problem.

The second problem is that one of the possible variants of record inside `objects` can have a key -- "depends" let's say -- whose value may assume different types.  It can either be a single record

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "depends": {
        "reference": "r1"
      },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

or a list of records

```
{
  "objects": [
    "depends": [
      {"reference": "r1"},
      {"reference": "r2"},
      etc.
    ],
  ],
...
}
```

and it happens that this is the one field that I would like to manipulate in a custom fashion after converting to a Haskell object (eventually I want to represent the collection of such "depends" references as a `Data.Graph` graph).

My initial attempt was to create one huge record type that subsumes all of the possible keys in the elements of the `objects` and `parameters` arrays.  Something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards   #-}

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

data Ref = Ref
  { ref :: String
  } deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON)

data Reference 
  = Reference Ref
  | References [Ref]
  deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON, ToJSON)

type MString = Maybe String -- I'm writing this a lot using this approach

data PObject = PObject 
  -- Each of the object/parameter records have these keys
  { _name    :: String
  , _id      :: String

  -- Other keys that might appear in a given object/parameter record
  , _type    :: MString
  , _role    :: MString
  , _depends :: Maybe Reference

  -- A bunch more
  } deriving Show

instance FromJSON PObject where
  parseJSON = withObject "PObject" $ \o -> do
    _name    <- o .: "name"
    _id      <- o .: "id"
    _type    <- o .:? "type"
    _role    <- o .:? "role"
    _depends <- o .:? "depends"
    -- etc.
    return PObject{..}
```

And then finally, the whole JSON object would be represented like

```
data MyJSONObject = MyJSONObject
  { objects    :: Maybe [PObject]
  , parameters :: Maybe [PObject]
  , values     :: Maybe Object
  } deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON)
```

This works until it tries to parse a "depends" field, reporting that

```
"Error in $.objects[2].depends: key \"tag\" not present"
```

There are no "tag" keys, so I'm not sure what this means.  I suspect it has to do with the generic instances of `FromJSON` for `Ref` and `Reference`.

**My questions:**

1. What does this error indicate?  So far in my learning of Haskell, the errors have always been very helpful.  This one is not.  Do I need to do something special for the "depends" key in my `parseJSON` function?
2. All of this boilerplate is really because of two keys -- "type" and "depends".  Is there a more elegant way to deal with these keys?
3. Relatedly, this is part of my first *real* Haskell project, so I have a more general design question.  Experienced Haskellers and Aeson users, how would you lay out your types and instances for this type of JSON?  I tried listing out each possible variant of `objects`/`parameters` record as its own separate type, and only writing custom `FromJSON` instances for those that have a "depends" or "type" key, but this produced a lot more boilerplate code and in any case doesn't solve any of the other issues I have.  General pointers on "best practices", idiomatic usage, etc. would be extremely useful and appreciated.

Comment: Try to boil it down to a single question. Your third question can be answered on [CodeReview.SE] as soon as your code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are no "tag" keys, so I'm not sure what this means. I suspect it has to do with the generic instances of `FromJSON` for `Ref` and `Reference`.

That's spot on. By [default,](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:defaultOptions) aeson will use the [`defaultTaggedObject`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:defaultTaggedObject) to encode sum types. `References` is a sum type. Therefore, aeson introduces a tag to distinguish the constructors. You can try that with a short example:

```
ghci> data Example = A () | B deriving (Generic,ToJSON)
ghci> encode B
"{\"tag\":\"B\",\"contents\":[]}"
```

When you use `_depends <- o .:? "depends"`, the `Reference` parser does not find its tag. You have to write some parsing code there yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> All of this boilerplate is really because of two keys -- "type" and
>   "depends". Is there a more elegant way to deal with these keys?

You could keep the underscores in the field names and use [`fieldLabelModifier`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:fieldLabelModifier) in the [`Options`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Options) data type to strip them for parsing purposes.